# How to select data from a *.dat file?

Tags: data, filtering

Good evening,
I have a *.dat file with four columns of data, $ \{t, x_1, x, y\} $. I would like to create another *.dat file containing all the $ y $ corresponding to $ x = x_1 $.

Could you please give me suggestions on how to select only those $ y $?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Select[dat, #[[2]] == #[[3]]&]` would select all rows which have x1 == x.

Comment: [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) would be better suited than Mathematica for this task.

Comment: There is no standard format called "dat file". How to read/write in your format depends on what the format actually is. This should be described precisely and unambiguously in the question.

Answer (score 4):

As [MassDefect suggested in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212319/how-to-select-data-from-a-dat-file#comment543801_212319), you can use `Select` to filter out the rows that do not satisfy your condition:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
dat = RandomInteger[100, {3000000, 4}];

Select[dat, #[[2]] == #[[3]] &]
```

However, [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) will be faster, if that's a concern:

```
Cases[dat, {_, x_, x_, _}]
```

You can compare timings and confirm that the results are the same with the two approaches:

```
RepeatedTiming[select = Select[dat, #[[2]] == #[[3]] &];]   (* Out: {3.3, Null} *)
RepeatedTiming[cases = Cases[dat, {_, x_, x_, _}];]         (* Out: {1.3, Null} *)
select === cases                                            (* Out: True        *)
```

---

Furthermore, if you really only want a list of the $y$ values for which the condition is true, that's very easy to obtain with `Cases` with almost no time penalty:

```
Cases[dat, {_, x_, x_, y_} :> y]
```

You can then export either result using e.g. `Export["filename.dat", yourResult, "Table"]`; look up [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) and [the `"Table"` export format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) in the docs.